# Need help to solve mysql and odbc query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, odbc

Hello im developing an application where data comes from MSSQL database. Here using php odbc connection i get all the needed data to work with app. But now i have a problem:

**Im looking for:**

All data from mssql (assume) mssql_Table_A will be listed in this app, each row will be given with checkbox so user can check the data required, after checking When he hit save checked data will be stored in local MySQL database (assume) mysql_table_A.

So next time when he again wants few more data, this app will list all the data from mssql_table_A which dont exists in mysql_table_A.

**Problem is:**

If both the dataflwo were from MYSQL i would have done this where easily by using mysql select query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mysql_table_a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mysql_table_B WHERE thisID != thatID)")
```

But here how do i check data exists in mysql table and list the data from odbc mssql database.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thank You..

Comment: are you using mssql or mysql?

Comment: Im using mysql to store the checked data, because all data are coming from mssql, im connected through php odbc to mssql to retreive all data, i would have flagged the selected data in mssql itself, but i'm provided only read access to mssql database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mssql_`, `sqlsrv_` or `PDO` functions to connect to MSSQL. `mysql_` functions are strictly for MySQL.

- [Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php)
- [Microsoft SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Functions (PDO_SQLSRV)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

You will need two separate connections if you are fetching data from both.

Alternatively, you can connect to MySQL from MSSQL using an ODBC connection and perform your query on the MSSQL side.

Comment: I dont have problem with retreiving data, can you please tell me how to check if the data from mssql exists in mysql so that if it exists i can skip those and list only which or not exists.
    odbc_exec($odbc_conn, $query)
    mysql($query, $mysqlConn)

Comment: @sravis You can put the data into an array and compare the arrays. However, it would be better if you did an ODBC connection from MSSQL directly to MySQL.

Comment: there are huge amount of data from mssql (like more than 1000 records per day), i have a 2 different php connection 1 for odbc and other for mysql, both are running fine, but how do i check if record exists in mysql table from fetching it from mssql? Using array i dont think it will be a better idea since there is huge amount of data, can you please tell me the query that can check the existing records in mysql and then list from not existing records from mssql.

Comment: @sravis Take a look at [this article](http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/) on how to link MySQL to MSSQL. After you establish a linked server, you can write a query from the MySQL table in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have told you how to connect the two databases but based on your comments you still want to know how to do the comparison.

I have to assume you've got at least one column which you can uniquely identify rows in table_a which are not in table_b. If you link mysql in MS SQL Server like one answer said you can

```
select * from mssql.table_a where unique_column not in (select unique_column from mysql.table_b)
```

but this works because mssql is linked to mysql in mssql i.e., you can do one query and mssql will do the join for you.

If for some reason you cannot or don't want to link mysql to ms sql via a linked table the easiest way would be if you had some sort of timestamp in table_a. Let's say every record written into table_a has a timestamp of when it was inserted:

```
mysql connection does select max(timestamp) into X from mysql.table_b
mssql connection does select * from mssql.table_a where timestamp > X
```

There may be other ways if we knew a bit more about your data.